# How can I check the GPU accessibility with Tensorflow on Mac of Apple M1 silicon?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, apple-silicon, apple-m1

I'm using Tensorflow 2.4.0 on Macbook(arm64, M1 silicon), I get this output after I wanted to check if the GPU in M1 silicon can be used by Tensorflow:

My code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.test.gpu_device_name())
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
```

The output:

```
[]
```

It looks like my GPU is unavailable. How should I use my GPU on M1 to accelerate trainning?

Comment: You can't......

Comment: `tensorflow.python.compiler.mlcompute.is_apple_mlc_enabled()`?

Comment: @talonmies reasoning?

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r, ...note the date; `tensorflow-metal` didn't exist yet when that comment was posted.

Answer (score 3):

As of July 2021 Apple [provide the following instructions](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/) to install Tensorflow 2.5 and the `tensorflow-metal` plugin:

1. Create a new conda environment;
2. Run `conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps`
3. Install tensorflow: `python -m pip install tensorflow-macos`; then
4. Install the plugin: `python -m pip install tensorflow-metal`.

This will give you access to the M1 GPU in Tensorflow.

**Update as of July 2023**

From TensorFlow 2.13 onwards this has been simplified to:

1. Create a new virtual environment using conda/venv/etc.
2. Install tensorflow: `python -m pip install tensorflow`; then
3. Install the plugin: `python -m pip install tensorflow-metal`.

Comment: Now that OS Monterey is available, upgrade your OS and then this should work ok.

Comment: @jeffhale works for me on OS Big Sur as well

Answer (score -2):

You may need to install [these Tensorflow addons](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos) for macOS 11.0+.

Comment: did't find way to check gpu availability but... I moved my code to Colab and it runs well! thx!

Comment: Please add enough information as text for the answer to remain useful even if links contained therein break. Even just changing "these Tensorflow addons" to "Apple's tensorflow_macos library", f/e, would be a substantial help: it would let someone find the new repository if it were renamed, if Apple decided not to use hosting owned by a competitor, &c.